# Piping search term (not filename) to grep

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

I want to pick out certain lines containing a given number from a file.
The file I want to search is called `os_clusters/piRNA_clusters.bed`.

```
awk '{if (a[$0]++ == 0) {split($0,b,"."); ;split(b[1],c,"r"); print c[3]}};' test_non_enriched | xargs grep {} os_clusters/piRNA_clusters.bed
```

The first part, before the pipe, works- it produces the terms to search for, such as 8707, 8824 etc.
However, the latter part does not.

```
awk '' ... | xargs grep {} os_clusters/piRNA_clusters.bed
```

Instead of searching the target file for the terms produced by the pipe, it considers the search terms as the input file.
Hence, I get error messages like:

```
grep: 8707: No such file or directory
grep: 8824: No such file or directory
```

What do I need to change to search the file `os_clusters/piRNA_clusters.bed` for the terms produced by the pipe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641731/read-expression-for-grep-from-standard-input

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think you want

```
... | grep -f - os_clusters/piRNA_clusters.bed
```

`-f` tells `grep` to obtain its search pattern from a file and `-` tells it that this file is actually stdin (the output of the pipe in your case).

Thanks to @rici's comment, for non-GNU `grep` use

```
... | grep -f /dev/stdin os_clusters/piRNA_clusters.bed
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it just produced: `grep: -: No such file or directory`

Comment: If you're not using gnu grep, try `-f /dev/stdin` instead of `-f -`

Comment: OS X 10.8 aka Mountain Lion

Comment: You can also use bash's `<()` syntax: `grep -f <(awk ...) os_clusters/piRNA_clusters.bed`