# How do I get a count of file references inside a folder of files with those references?

Tags: files, grep, search

Alright, I have two folders. For simplicity's sake, I'll call them `players` and `items`. The items folder has a file for each item, and the people folder has a file for each person with references to which animals that person owns. This is what I have so far:

```
ls -1 ~/items | cut -d. -f1 | grep -R -f - ~/player
```

The grep syntax I got from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85461/piping-search-term-not-filename-to-grep). I'm trying to get it to say:

```
electric: 8
laser: 7
loltrail: 2
```

Instead, I add the `-c` flag to `grep` and I get:

```
Bob.txt: 0
Cathy.txt: 0
John.txt: 0
Patrick.txt: 1
```

How do I get counts of the items in total, not the items for each person?

This is for figuring out how many items are being used in the [Pointshop](https://github.com/adamdburton/pointshop) addon for Garry's Mod.

Comment: So you just want to add all the numbers obtained from grep output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a way to get the results you want with GNU `awk`:

```
awk '
    BEGINFILE {
        if (FILENAME ~ "^animals/"  ||  FILENAME ~ "/animals/") {
                this_name = substr(FILENAME, index(FILENAME,"animals/")+length("animals/"))
                i = index(this_name, ".")
                if (i > 0) this_name = substr(this_name, 1, i-1)
                critter[++num] = this_name
                critter_count[num] = 0
                nextfile
        }
    }
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                if ($0 ~ critter[i]) critter_count[i]++
        }
    }
    END {
        for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) print critter[i] ": " critter_count[i]
    }
'  animals/*  people/*
```

- Upon starting a new file (`BEGINFILE`),
  check whether its name begins with `animals/` or contains `/animals/`. 
  This lets you say `animals/*`, `./animals/*`, or `~/animals/*`. 
  If it does,

  - Extract the substring to the right of `animals/`.
  - Then look for a `.`; if found, extract the substring to the left of it.
  - Add this string (the base filename, with directory and extension removed)
    to the `critter[]` array,
    and initialize the corresponding `critter_count` to 0.

  ☛  Note that `BEGINFILE` and `nextfile` are not available in POSIX awk.
- Otherwise (if we’re looking at a `people` file),
  loop through the animal names (`critter`s)
  and count the lines that match them.
- Upon reaching the `END` of all input,
  report the animal names
  that were extracted from the names of the `animals` files,
  and the counts of how often each appeared in a `people` file.

This won’t search the `people` directory recursively;
I didn’t see any statement in the question that that was desired.

Comment: Would it take me 8 years to reply to and finally accept an answer for the Garry's Mod server I was running? No, no no no of course not. Though I may be packing up to move and have seen all these files go over the wire to my NAS and remembered this lol.

Comment: This was originally to get a count of items used in the Pointshop addon for a Garry's Mod server, which by your name I assume you're a fan of Half-Life 2 or Doki Doki Literature Club? Well, thank you very much for this write-up and I'm glad I can finally check this off my to-do list from 2015.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you give the patterns as input to `grep` using `stdin`, it will concatenate results for all patterns. So AFAIK the only way to overcome this problem is to call a new instance of grep for each pattern.

This script would work in this case

```
for animalName in $(ls -1 ~/animals | cut -d. -f1);
    do
        echo "$animalName: $(grep -R -h -c $animalName ~/people | paste -sd+ | bc)";
done
```

This is on the lines of what you have tried with some minor changes. First, `-h` option in `grep` suppresses printing of file names. Second, with just `grep`, output for a pattern would be like

```
1
0
3
2
```

We want to add all these numbers. `paste` command joins these lines with a `+` and then passes the formed string to `bc` to calculate the result.

NOTE: If your animal names contain newlines or any special characters (in some strange land), it is not advisable to parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: This worked too! Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up going with the awk answer because that gives more leeway in what can be added to the script in the future. For instance, each item is in a category and I could count which categories are most popular.